# What does the tx req option disable ack exactly in the xbee API?

Tags: network-protocols, xbee, zigbee

The question, as mentioned in the title, is what causes the tx option field with the value 0x01 (disable ack) exactly. I assumed it disables the *aps* layer acknowledgement and the additional *aps* retries. But they occur in any way with *aps* acknowledgment disabled, too. The retry counter of the tx status frame counts still, sometimes till 60. I think this is a bit too much for the *mac* layer retries. Or there are also retries in *nwk* layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Option 0x01 on TX Request (API frame) doesn't disable the acknowledgment, it does disable the retries (up to 3). The following is a example of a TX Request frame with retries disable:

7E 00 0F 10 01 00 13 A1 00 40 AA D0 06 FF FE 00 **01** 04 78

For you to disable the acknowledgement you need to set 0x00 on Frame ID of TX Request. Here is an example:

7E 00 0F 10 **00** 00 13 A1 00 40 AA D0 06 FF FE 00 00 04 7A

I guess the Transmit Retry Count (from ZigBee Transmit Status frame) is related to CSMA-CA.